# Return a function pointer without a typedef

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that returns a function pointer without using any typedefs. The returned function needs to be assignable to

```
static int (*compare_function)(int a);
```

Is this the best/only way to do it?

```
static static int (*compare_function)(int a)
assign_compare_function(int a,...,char* z){
//blah
}
```

There are two statics because I want the assigner function to be static as well.

Comment: Will this work? Try it and tell us..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry :) what I meant was, is this the correct/idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: Why not use a `typedef`? If it is a part of an interface, the correct way would be to use it.

Comment: The only reason I can think of to avoid a `typedef` would be because this is an academic exercise that imposes such a requirement.

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) can help you sort out the meanings of C declarations.  Your compiler can help you confirm your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem problem with your definition is that it makes zero sense to write `static static`.  This is because `static` is a *storage qualifier* and it's not part of the type per se.  The second problem is that you need a parameter list for both functions.

You can write this:

```
int (*compare_function(void))(int a) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can make `compare_function` static:

```
static int (*compare_function(void))(int a) {
    ...
}
```

Either of these will return an object of type `int (*)(int a)` which is what you want.  To clarify, without using `typedef`, this is the only way to write a function that returns a function (not counting someo

Writing `static static` makes no sense.  Imagine writing something like:

```
// no
typedef static int SInt;
```

That just doesn't make any sense either, so when you have a variable:

```
static int (*compare_function)(int a);
```

The type is `int (*)(int)`, and the storage duration is static, and the linkage is internal.

Comment: You're quite right, but you seem to have missed the point of the question, which is how to write a signature for a function whose return type is that function pointer type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Does "You can write `int (*compare_function)(int a)`" not cover that?  I'm confused why you think that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @DietrichEpp - but you're essentially confirming that his first line of code is perhaps the "best" or most "idiomatic" way to go about returning a function pointer w/out a `typedef`?

Comment: @MattGalaxy: I find the wording "best" or "idiomatic" a bit perplexing since there is only in fact one way to write the type signature for a function that returns a function pointer without a typedef.  It's like asking for the "best" way to declare an `int` named `x`, you can either write `int x;` or you can go outside and go for a walk in the park, but only one of those things will actually declare an `int` named `x`.

Comment: No, your answer does not answer the question.  Given variable `compare_function` declared as you have presented at the end of your answer, the question asks not how to declare a function to which that variable can point, but how to declare a function whose *return value* can be assigned to that variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sorry, typo, fixed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Overall overall great answer.  To relate it back to the OP- would the function declaration of `static int (*assign_compare_function(void))(int a,...,char* z)` still be assignable to the lvalue `static int (*compare_function(void))(int a)`?

Comment: @MattGalaxy: You can assign the output of `int x;` to `static int x;`.  Remember that `static` is not part of the type.

Comment: @MattGalaxy: I am a little skeptical: are you actually wondering about the answer, or are you asking this question on behalf of the OP?  Because if you are asking on behalf of the OP, we might rather wait and give the OP a chance to formulate their own questions.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: pure curiosity on my part!  Mostly because your answer seems to address the definition of a `compare_function` variable as opposed to the return value of `assign_compare_function`.  Or..  I'm just really confused & should brush up on function pointers...

Comment: @MattGalaxy: `static` is a bit confusing because it means different things in different contexts.  However, for the purpose of "can I assign X to Y", you can ignore `static` altogether.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Thanks for [bearing](http://files.explosm.net/comics/Kris/bored3.png) with me :)  ~ While I understand static declaration, I submitted my own answer in an attempt to show you where my confusion lies.  Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to correctly return function pointer:

```
int compare_function(int a);

int (*assign_compare_function())(int)
{
  return compare_function;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword static is a scope qualifier. It is not part of the type itself.

```
int (*compare_function)(int a);
```

This specifies the function taking int 'a' returning int. You can use the compare_function at after this statement to reference a type to that function signature.

You could assign it:

```
static int my_compare_function(int a)
{
    return a - 10;   // stupid implementation
}

compare_function = my_compare_function;
```

Notice that my_compare_function has the static qualifier.